# VS 2012 on windows 8 and click once publish

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I've got a fresh build of windows 8 running Visual Studio 2012 version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3.  I have a winform app that I have been using (when the machine was running windows 7).  The file structure where i'm trying to get to is the same as it was on windows 7.  I'm a local admin.  I'm trying to publish the to the location of c:\inetput\wwwroot\deploy\SCC (again.. where I was doing it on windows 7, but on windows 7 I was using Visual studio 2010).  I receive an error on each file that is a application files. The errors follow this line

Error   1   Failed to copy file 'C:\Bob\SCC\SCC\MailProcessor\bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\MailProcessor_1_0_0_32\dbConfig.dll.deploy' to 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Deploy/SCC/Application Files/MailProcessor_1_0_0_32/dbConfig.dll.deploy'. Unable to add 'Application Files/MailProcessor_1_0_0_32/dbConfig.dll.deploy' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Application Files\MailProcessor_1_0_0_32\dbConfig.dll.deploy'.  The system cannot find the path specified.
        1   1   MailProcessor

The solution builds without errors, just get these errors when I attempt to publish to my local IIS.  Was hoping someone had already figured out how to fix this.

Thanks
Shannon

Answer (score 1):

I am able to publish ClickOnce apps to localhost in Windows 8/VS2012. Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator? You have to do this in order to publish to the local webserver. Are there any files at all being deployed to the inetpub folder? Do you have full IIS installed locally (not IIS Express)?